# Using generators on networks ending with tensorflow probability layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras, tensorflow-probability

I have a network which ends with probability layer something like this:

```py
model = tfk.Sequential([
            tfkl.InputLayer(10),
            tfkl.Dense(tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL.params_size(2)),
            tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL(2)])
```

And I am creating my dataset from a generator:

```py
data_generator = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
            data_generator,
            output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32)
).batch(batch_size)
```

I am able to fit the model with `fit_generator` but how can I do the same for prediction? (I have tried `predict_generator`, but no success)

Moreover, if `X` is a numpy array I can just do `model(X).sample(100)` I want to do the same with my generator, something like `model(data_generator).sample(100)`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add one more layer:

```
model = tfk.Sequential([
    tfkl.InputLayer(10),
    tfkl.Dense(tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL.params_size(2)),
    tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL(2),
    tfkl.Lambda(lambda x: tf.transpose(x.sample(100), perm=[1,0,2]))])
```

and then use

```
model.predict_generator(data_generator, steps=steps)
```

Or do you need to do more with the resulting distribution than just sample?

Edit: because in that case, maybe you could just create a generator that feeds batches to the model as numpy arrays and yields the resulting distributions?